# Formula to calculate size of Capsule output similar to the formula for CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, computer-vision

Is there any formula to find the output dimensions of a capsule network similar to that of a Convolutional Neural Network?

For Example: In CNN, we know that

```
(W - F + 2P/S)+1 = output_size where W = Dimensions of Input, F= Filter Size, p= Padding and S = Stride
```

Kindly note that the same formula does not work for capsule networks as well.